# Octave 7.1.0 opens with cryptic error/warning messages

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I've just installed Octave 7.1.0 and I noticed a strange sequence of error/warning messages which I had never seen before nor am able to decipher:

```
2022-05-06T16:59:34.366ZE [6832:ShellIpcClient] message_loop.cc:133:Run Run called on MessageLoop that's already been Quit!
2022-05-06T16:59:34.368ZE [12660:ShellIpcClient] message_loop.cc:133:Run Run called on MessageLoop that's already been Quit!
2022-05-06T16:59:34.369ZE [8132:ShellIpcClient] message_loop.cc:133:Run Run called on MessageLoop that's already been Quit!
2022-05-06T16:59:34.371ZE [15212:ShellIpcClient] message_loop.cc:133:Run Run called on MessageLoop that's already been Quit!
```

Since I haven't had the time to test this new version (a mere 1/2 hour has passed since I installed it) I cannot tell whether or not Octave's functionality is compromised.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever this message comes from, it is not from Octave. Someone reported the same issue last year on Octave's forum at [Strange opening messages when opening Octave each time](https://octave.discourse.group/t/strange-opening-messages-when-opening-octave-each-time/1712/4) which links to a similar issue on the [Far Manager bug tracker](https://bugs.farmanager.com/view.php?id=3832). The Far Manager devs suggest that this comes from Google drive:

> When you open a context menu, all registered shell extensions are loaded into the Far process. These extensions implement custom context menu items, shown by various software. Sometimes the authors of these extensions add various debug logging messages to their code to see what is going on in various situations. Sometimes these authors are too lazy to implement a proper logging and they just print stuff to the standard output stream, connected to a console. Windows Explorer doesn't have a console attached to it, so all these messages go into the void. Far, on the contrary, does have a permanently attached console - you're looking at it. Therefore, any debug stuff these lazy people print in their extensions ends up in that console.
>
> It's quite sad, but there's nothing we can do about it.
>
> Please search for that string ("Run Run called on MessageLoop that`s already been Quit") in your Program Files folder and, once found, report to the corresponding product owners. I suspect that in your case it's Google Drive.

Comment: Fine, but then why previous Octave versions did not show those messages? First time I see them. I also wonder what Google Drive has to do with this. So far, Octave 7.1.0 has worked well.